# inserting user in database from regitration form laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i am working on a e-commerce website using laravel 8 for the first time i created a login and registration views, when i try registering  first it flashed iccorrect email adresse in session error that is displayed in register.blade.php after fixing that it redirected me to an error page with this text :

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
http://localhost:3000/create?_token=7vVwL33yaBmkmsJIKHl78XfzZNmk4vJDBG9qumhf&email=theoghmir.kodia%40laposte.net&name=HELLh&password=2223541
```

my route is acctually set to POST did i forget some thing ? here is my web.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\authController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/auth', [authController::class, 'authpage']);
Route::get('/auth/check', [authController::class, 'check'])->name('auth.check');
Route::get('/register', [authController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/create', [authController::class, 'create'])->name('auth.create');
Route::get('/logout', [authController::class, 'logout']);
```

here the register.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('auth.create')}}" methode="POST">
    @if(Session::get('fail'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{Session::get('fail')}}</div>
    @endif 
    @if(Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
    @endif 
    @csrf
    <label>name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder=" name..." >
    <label>Email :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder=" email..." value="{{old('email')}}">
    <span class="text-danger">
    @error ('email') {{$message}} @enderror</span><br>
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe...">
    <span class="text-danger">
    @error ('password') {{$message}} @enderror</span><br>
    <button type="submit">S'inscrir</button>

</form>
```

here is the auth controller with the methode create() :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\hash;

class authController extends Controller
{
    public function authpage()
    {
       return view('login');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|min:5|max:12',
        ]);
        $user = new User ;
        $user -> name = $request->name;
        $user -> email = $request->email;
        $user -> password = $request->password;
        $query = $user->save();
        if($query) {
            return back()->with('success',' vous êtes inscris avec succées  ! ' );
        }else{
            return back()->with('fail',' il y as quelque chose qui cloche ! ' );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an syntax error, it is not `methode=` but `method="POST"`

```
<form action="{{ route('auth.create')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: @Mcyes has added `@csrf`.

Comment: Sorry true. The method="post" syntax is the failure ;)